# PHP combine arrays with logical operator

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a way to combine boolean arrays:

```
$array1: ['prop1'=>T, 'prop2'=>F, 'prop3'=>T, 'prop4'=>F, 'prop5'=>T]
$array2: ['prop1'=>T, 'prop2'=>F, 'prop3'=>F, 'prop4'=>T]
```

Into

```
$array3: ['prop1'=>T, 'prop2'=>F, 'prop3'=>T, 'prop4'=>T, 'prop5'=>T]
```

Using the *OR* comparison?

I thought using `$array3 = $array1 | $array2` would work but it returns a single value.

I feel like this could be a duplicate but I failed to find the same question on SO.

Comment: You can't have two keys named the same: `$array3['prop1']`, guessing you meant `prop3`?

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys, but I *assume* that the second instance of `prop1` in both arrays was meant to be `prop3`. If so, how does one 'combine' them, as they have differing values? Are you trying to say that **if** either array contains a `true` value for the relevant key, push to the third array?

Comment: @Scuzzy Looks like a typo setting up their MVCE

Comment: Fixed, my mistake guys!

Answer (score 0):

While each array have the same key you can use foreach loop to loop through the first array check if equally then you set the key and value to result array else if not equally then use the one with true value

```
$result=array();  
foreach($array1 as $key=>$value){
  if($array1[$key]==$array2[$key] || $array2==undefined){
    $result[$key]=$value;
  }
  else{
    $result[$key]=($array1[$key]==True)?$array1[$key] : $array2[$key];
  }
}
```

Then loop through second array to see if the key is undefined in first to add the key value from second array

```
foreach($array2 as $key=>$value){
  if ($array1[$key]==undefined){
    $result[$key]=$value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest solution I can think of. And it's really not that complicated :). First we add the two arrays to make sure all keys exist in `$result`. Then we use the [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) to perform the logical operation.

We need 3 arguments. The first is the `$result` variable we want to manipulate.
The third argument gets passed to our callback. We again use an array sum to ensure all keys are set, but this time `$array2` gets the precedence.

The second is our callback. We get each value from the preliminary result by reference (&), each key by value, and our wish as a third parameter. The function itself is really simple we just set `$v` to whatever operation we want to implement. `||` for OR, `&&` for AND or xor for XOR (but xor needs additional parentheses, see [Operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/fa/language.operators.precedence.php)).

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/PGKPZ)

```
$array1 = ['prop1'=>TRUE, 'prop2'=>FALSE, 'prop3'=>TRUE, 'prop4'=>TRUE];
$array2 = ['prop1'=>TRUE, 'prop2'=>TRUE, 'prop3'=>FALSE, 'prop5'=>FALSE];
$result = $array1 + $array2;

array_walk($result, function(&$v, $k, $a){
   $v = $v || $a[$k]; //Here you can change the operation
}, $array2+$array1);

var_dump($result);
```